# plotting scatter plot in python clearly with each tick visible

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have around 45 csv files each containing two columns with 13,000 entries I want to plot all these csv files together in a single scatter plot and dont want the ticks of the scatter plot to overlap with each other i want all the ticks to be visible clearly in the scatter plot.

I am attaching the core below where i am combining all these scatter plots and plotting them in a single plot.the output is a scatter plot which is every clumsy to understand the reason i am asking for all the points to be clearly visible without overlapping is study them for my research.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

csv_directory = "Allplots/graphs"

csv_files = [file for file in os.listdir(csv_directory) if file.endswith(".csv")]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

all_indices = []
all_accuracies = []

for csv_file in csv_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(csv_directory, csv_file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    
    bit_index = df[" Index"]
    accuracy = df["Accuracy"]
    
    all_bit_indices.extend(index)
    all_accuracies.extend(accuracy)

plt.scatter(all_indices, all_accuracies, s=10)

plt.xlabel("Index (Millions)", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Accuracy", fontsize=12)
plt.title("Scatter Plot of Accuracy vs. Bit Index", fontsize=14)

# Save the plot as a PNG file
output_path = os.path.join(csv_directory, "scatter_plot.png")
plt.savefig(output_path)

plt.show()
```

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmtEp.png)

I also want to plot these CSV files serailly say the first portion of graph should have points from csv1 file then csv2 file then so on i dont want the points of all csv files to mix up.

Comment: Please either share the data, use random numbers so we can run the code, or include the figure in your post.

Comment: I have added the image under the link scatter plot below the code

Comment: By 'tick', do you mean the individual data point markers? Tick usually refers to the tick marks/labels on the x,y axis.

Comment: i mean individual data point markers not labels.sorry for the confusion

Comment: You could experiment with smaller dot sizes and using alpha for semi-transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the various marker parameters in `pyplot.scatter`. I recommend lowering `s` for smaller marker size, changing `marker = '.'` (default is 'o') for a smaller marker shape, and/or adjusting `edgecolors = None` or `edgecolors = 'face'` so the marker doesn't have an obvious outline.

For example: `plt.scatter(all_indices, all_accuracies, s=1, marker = '.', edgecolors = 'face')`

Comment: I also want to plot these CSV files serailly say the first portion of graph should have points from csv1 file then csv2 file then so on i dont want the points of all csv files to mix up.

Comment: @saras What do you mean by different "portions" of the plot?

Comment: Apologies about that, the above answer solved my problem.Thank you for the help .